# Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow when using DATEADD

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm running into an issue with SQL Server `DATEADD()` which seems to differ between server versions - ServerOne uses 13.0 (SQL Server 2016), ServerTwo uses 15.0 (SQL Server 2019). The error raised from `DATEADD()` is shown below. Both servers have the same compatibility mode - 100.

This issue can be raised on both servers using a simple statement such as the below, which understandably results in the error below.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59')
```

> Msg 517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

However, when running the below update statement, this error is only raised on ServerTwo, not ServerOne.

This `UPDATE` is expected to run without making modifications to the data in cases where `@VariableA` and `@VariableB` are `NULL`. These are a legacy stored procedure and view (which cannot change at this time) I'm needing to resolve the error in the case where the variables aren't assigned values.

In this casel, this is understandably raised because the default value of `ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField` is `9999-12-31 23:59:59` (as defined in the view) when `@VariableA` and `@VariableB` are `NULL` but it seems it's still retrieving the value for `TableB.IntField` and thus causing the overflow.

```
-- Unset purposefully to mimic when values are not given a value elsewhere in the procedure        
DECLARE @VariableA INT, 
        @VariableB INT;

UPDATE TableA
SET BooleanField = 1
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN ViewA ON TableA.Id = ViewA.Id
INNER JOIN TableB ON ViewA.Id = TableB.Id
WHERE (ISNULL(TableB.BooleanField, 'FALSE') = 'FALSE'
       OR GETDATE() < DATEADD(DAY, ISNULL(TableB.IntField, 0), ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField))
  AND (TableA.Id = @VariableA OR TableA.Id = @VariableB);
```

In the case where `TableB.IntField` is `NULL`, no error is raised as it doesn't attempt to perform addition to the upper bound (default value) date of `ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField`. The field behind `ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField` always has a valid `DATETIME` value.

Some strange things I've noticed - if only one variable is used in the second condition block, the error doesn't occur. If no variables are used (substituted with `NULL` directly), the error doesn't happen, but this may well just be a symptom of the order of execution when variables are removed. Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand what might have changed between the versions which means that the error isn't raised on the older server but does so on the newer one.

Having checked some migrations guides (below) for SQLServer 2016 and SQLServer 2019, I don't see any direct references to the output of the function, nor changes in strictness or ordering around such uses of it.

- [Supported version and edition upgrades (SQL Server 2019)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2019?view=sql-server-ver16)
- [Deprecated Database Engine features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Deprecated Database Engine features in SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Deprecated database engine features in SQL Server 2019 (15.x)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2019?view=sql-server-ver15)

The view is defined below (other fields omitted for simplicity)

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewA
AS 
    SELECT 
        Id,
        DateTimeField,
        LEAD(DateTimeField, 1, '9999-12-31 23:59:59') OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY DateTimeField) AS PartitionedDateTimeField
    FROM 
        dbo.TableX
```

Could this be as simple as a difference in the query plan/execution orders between servers? When run with only a single variable undefined, the execution plans seem the same. Might I have missed something relating to the difference in server versions? The data has been staged on one server to mimic the other, therefore, I don't believe that in itself could be the issue.

Comment: The error your describe will, and does, occur on [2022](https://dbfiddle.uk/RvT4BRfD), [2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/RYqIxCIe), [2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/rekQ9J6y), [2016](https://dbfiddle.uk/UuYrU1Mu) and even a 2012 instance I still have kicking around. If you aren't getting the error on one server, I would suggest that the values aren't what you think that are; none of the date and time values in SQL Server can have a value > 9999-12-31T23:59:59(.9999999).

Comment: it could be something to do with query plans, depending on evaluation order, maybe on one server the dateadd is performed ahead of variable check. This is same issue as when you write: select 1 where isnumeric(sometext) = 1 and sometext < 40.3 . Bad query that doesn't guarantee evaluation order is bad.

Comment: Plus, you didn't ask any question?

Comment: @siggemannen I don't deny it's a poorly written segment of a poorly written procedure - but that's legacy code for you. I'm trying to better understand the possible reasons for this by asking for the experiences of others as to what might differ between the servers which could lead to this issue, or perhaps indeed if the server versioning may be nothing more than a red herring. I'm not suggesting it's incorrect to occur, and I've updated the question with questions, but it's the intermit nature that's interesting to me.

Comment: You can change your code to  DATEADD(DAY, ISNULL(case when getdate() = '19000101' then null else 0 end, 0)) and compare the two queryplans you get. This ensure the code doesn't crash and allows you to see the difference

Comment: And, what is the output of `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 2, '9999-12-31 23:59:59')`, on systems that produce an output?

Comment: @Luuk, i think that code fails everywhere :)

Comment: " this error is only raised on ServerTwo, not ServerOne."  So, question is unclear ?

Comment: I think on one server that part isn't evaluated at all, because it short-circuits some other condition first

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line

```sql
OR GETDATE() < DATEADD(DAY, ISNULL(TableB.IntField, 0), ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField))
```

has no guarantee on when it gets executed, so it may be executing on rows which have both the max value for `PartitionedDateTimeField` and a positive `IntField`, causing an overflow error. This is despite the fact these rows may be excluded by other clauses, as there is no guarantee on order of execution.

You can solve it like this

```sql
OR GETDATE() <
  DATEADD(DAY,
    ISNULL(CASE WHEN TableB.IntField BETWEEN -36500 AND 0 THEN TableB.IntField END, 0),
    ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField))
```

Alternatively you can remove the default parameter from the `LEAD` in the view, and check for nulls separately.

```sql
OR GETDATE() <
  DATEADD(DAY, ISNULL(TableB.IntField, 0), ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField)
OR ViewA.PartitionedDateTimeField IS NULL)
```